# How to display process information?

Tags: linux, system-calls, proc

I need to search a system call which lists the process information for a given process id. I don't want to do it by mapping the proc filesystem, because this requires root permission to get the pathname of the process (`/proc/<pid>/exe`), where the process is a kernel thread.

Comment: Can you be specific about what process information you want?  Generally, the `proc` file system is the canonical way to get most info, or else parsing `ps` output (which is much the same thing).

Comment: I want the pathname of process.

Comment: You mean the pathname of the executable?  As you've found, that's only available to the process's owner, or to root.  If there were a way to get it without those credentials, it would probably be a security flaw that should be fixed.

Comment: but why the htop command can do that ( get the pathnames of all processes ) without setuid file permission ?

Comment: It looks to me like `htop` displays the process command line (which you can get from `/proc/pid/cmdline`).  This sometimes contains the full path to the process executable, if the full path was included in `argv[0]` when the process `exec`ed, but not always.